# Input element disable bug between two divs

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have two divs that each contain input elements that hold data that are very different from each other. Each div is dependent on a value from a select element. When a user chooses a value from one div, that particular input element in that div is getting disabled. However, the issue I am facing is that at any given time only one input element from each is disabled. Since they hold different information it interferes with the logic.

Here's the code for the first div.

```
$.getJSON('/ResidentialBuilding/getYear', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $("#standards").append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + value.year + '"' + 'id="' + value.year + '">' + "<span>" + value.year + "</span>" + '</input><br>');
    });
});
$("#ResidentialStandardYear").change(function () {
    standardValue = $("#ResidentialStandardYear").val();
    console.log(standardValue);
    if (standardValue == $("#" + standardValue).attr('id')) {
        $('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', true);
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Here's the code for the second div

```
$("#ResidentialStandardPeriod").change(function () {
    period = $("#ResidentialStandardPeriod").val();
    console.log(period);
    if (period == $('#' + period).attr('id')) {
        $('#' + period).attr('disabled', true);
        $('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + period).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[image]

As the image shows, 2003 and 1 year are selected. However, in the first div 2003 is enabled which should be disabled. What exactly is the bug here?

Comment: `if (period == $('#' + period).attr('id'))` will always be true. What are you trying to test there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', false);
```

enables *all* other checkboxes, not just the ones in the current DIV. You need to restrict it to the corresponding DIV. Give the DIVs around the checkboxes IDs, and refer to those in the change handlers.

```
<div id="standardCB">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2003" value="2003">2003</input>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2006" value="2006">2006</input>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="periodCB">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1">1</input>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2">2</input>
    <br>
</div>

$("#standard").change(function () {
    stdval = $(this).val();
    console.log(stdval);
    if (stdval == $('#' + stdval).attr('id')) {
        $('#' + stdval).attr('disabled', true);
        $("#standardCB").find('input[type=checkbox]').not('#'+stdval).attr('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#period').change(function(){
    periodval = $(this).val();
    if (periodval == $('#'+periodval).attr('id')){
        $('#'+periodval).attr('disabled',true);
        $("#periodCB").find('input[type=checkbox]').not('#'+periodval).attr('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4VLTJ/2/)

Comment: That's what I thought was happening. I was trying to add and disable a class, but that did not work as I thought it would

Comment: That seems like an easier way to do it. Use a different class in each DIV, then it's `$(".thisCBclass:not(#"+standardValue+")").attr('disabled', false)`

Comment: Well, I tried your earlier approach. The disabled does not refresh when the select element is changed.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: My answer assumed that the dropdown and the related checkboxes were in the same DIV. If not, you need some way to relate them. Give the DIVs IDs and use that instead of `.closest()`, or use a class.

Comment: Got it. So I believe this works because when u use $('#standards).find(input), it only finds input elements that are within that particular div?

Comment: That's what `.find()` does -- it searches within that part of the DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57283/discussion-between-tarang-hirani-and-barmar).